# Select between two tables, two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to find all records in TableA which are not in TableB by comparing 2x columns in each table. I have tried all sorts of queries but I cannot figure it. Any help would be much appreciated.

TableA Has ColumnA and ColumnDate

TableB  Has ColumnA and ColumnDate

So I only want to see which records in TableA do not match TableB for both columns. 
Also, TableA may have several matching fields so I need to group them to have only 1 entry into TableB for each match.
Yes I want to insert the new records into TableB.
It appears harder than expected.

Something like this:

```
select ColumnDate, ColumnA
from TableA 
where 
(( ColumnDate not in (select ColumnDate from TableB) ) 
and ( ColumnA not in (select ColumnA from TableB) ))
group by ColumnA, ColumnDate;
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thank you Strawberry. I have searched for an answer, explained what I'm looking for, what the expected output is and left a sqlfiddle. What else should I be doing to get some help?

Comment: How come lukass gets a fiddle, but we don't? Edit your question in line with the accepted answer at the linked question- or don't

Comment: Here is a SQLFIDDLE. Example, ColumnA has multiple entries for '1027'. But the reults should only show 2x results for 1027 because 1027 is already in TableB for the other dates. Should only show 11 & 12th Feb for 1027: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d70c9a – Jamie T 2 days ago

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this, If I want to just sync two tables I use straight `INSERT SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO TableB (ColumnA, ColumnDate) 
SELECT FROM TableA (ColumnA, ColumnDate) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ColumnDate = ColumnDate
```

**But be careful**, you need to have *Primary Key* or *Unique* index on **TableB**, so the engine will only insert new rows based on uniqueness/pk of the receiving table.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. This isn't quite what I am loking for. TableA will have multiples of the same ColumnA and ColumnDate which are identical. I want to group the (into 1 record per match, and insert into TableB if there is no match in TableB.

Comment: Here is a SQLFIDDLE. Example, ColumnA has multiple entries for '1027'. But the reults should only show 2x results for 1027 because 1027 is already in TableB for the other dates. Should only show 11 & 12th Feb for 1027:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d70c9a